# Determining if a 1-0 matrix that represents a relation is transitive

Tags: python, matrix

I'm pretty sure that a 1-0 matrix representing a matrix is transitive a_ij= 1 == a_ji=1 implies that a_ii == 1 for a matrix a(not sure though). The problem is I am always returning true. Thanks for any help.

```
def transitive(a):
"""Returns True if the relation M is transitive, False otherwise."""
    assert (len(row) == len(M) for row in M)

    for i in range (len(a)):
        for j in range (len(a)):
        if (a[i][j] == 1 and a[j][i] == 1 and a[i][i] == 1):
                return True

    return False

print transitive([[1,0,1],[0,1,1],[0,1,1]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `return True` once you found one transitive link (and break the loop), not when you found the entire chain.

Instead, you could `return False` when you found a broken link (the condition in the loop does not hold), and `return True` if no such broken link was found.